# Why is Android doing things behind my back?

Tags: android

Or, in other words: what is the context's lifetime in Android?

I'm asking this because I get a **NullPointerException** when trying to access the context in the following code:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private transient Context _context;

    public MyClass() {
        _context = App.context();
        Log.d("is null: " + (_context == null)); // shows false
    }

    // other code (that doesn't touch context in any way)

    public void myMethod() {
        Log.d("is null: " + (_context == null)); // shows true!!!
        // WHY?!? for the love of God, WHY?!?
        // It was already initialized in the constructor!!!

        Log.d("is null: " + (App.context() == null)); // shows false
        Toast.makeText(_context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //                 ^ throws NullPointerException for _context
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `App` class:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Context $context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        App.$context = this;
    }

    public static Context context() {
        return $context;
    }
}
```

Why is Android doing things **behind my back**??? When I set a value to a variable I want it to stay **THE SAME** until I **EXPLICITLY** modify it.

---

### EDIT

Here is the code that calls `MyClass`:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Intent intent = new Intent(App.context(), MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mc", mc);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in `MyActivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        MyClass mc = (MyClass) bundle.get("mc");
        mc.myMethod(); // here it crashes, see previous code (before editing).
}
```

Comment: When your my method is getting called?

Comment: @thinksteep: please see my **Edit**. If you have other things that you need me to clarify, please ask.

Comment: is the context == null in your constructor supposed to have an underscore in front of it?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a small typo. Editing now...

Comment: It seems you don't want to serialize the context but want to pass your object as part of bundle. I suspect that is causing issue. Could you remove transient there and test it? I strongly feel that is the issue.

Comment: @thinksteep: well, I tried that already, but it throws another exception: "java.io.NotSerializableException: com.igorpopov.App"

Comment: Yeah, I know. As expected it is because you are trying to send context as part of bundle. My guess is you need to rethink your design. AFAIK you can't achieve passing context in a bundle.

Comment: @thinksteep: yeah, that's for sure... thank you very much for trying to help me :)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you. Enjoy programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I found the stupidity I did: the Context is **a transient member** and **it doesn't get serialized** when I pass it in a bundle. So when I get it out **it will obviously be null**.

I know I should use Parcelable instead of Serializable, but this is just a toy project sooo...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this at the beginning.

```
 private Context _context = null;
```

Comment: nope, not working... anyway I set the _context in the constructor and as shown in my example: it is NOT null.

Comment: mmm, I see... well it seems that something weird happens... but I have the sensation that some code is missing in the example, try to put everything so I can dive into it.

Comment: well, I think there're two options: Or the error is in the way of passing the "mc" var (check if they are the SAME instance) or is a retrieval problem. I have done several Android app and I've never had this problem (Although I always passed "simple" vars, not objects), so try to simplify the code

Answer (score 0):

i notices one thing: in the constructor you have

```
public MyClass() {
    _context = App.context();
    Log.d("is null: " + (context == null)); // shows false
}
```

where you check

```
context == null
```

the variable however is called _context. so where does the context variable ( without _ ) come from?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the following way:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();       
        App.context=getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Therefore, you can call `App.getAppContext()` from anywhere in your application.

Remove that Context member from MyClass, it is not a good approach:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    public void myMethod() {
        Toast.makeText(App.getAppContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //                 ^ throws NullPointerException for _context
    }
}
```